# Type Mismatch that is normally matched

Tags: vba, listbox, mismatch

I'm  working on a code in VBA that does the following operations :
- Look for the articles that have the same product of origin in a listbox (Listbox4)
- Add all the quantities
- Affect it to the original product in another listbox (Listbox2)

It was working yesterday but when I run it today it says that there is a Type Mismatch, which I don't see and It's driving me crazy. Here is the code

```
    For t = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
     dés = ListBox2.List(t, 0)
     quantité = 0
            For j = 12 To lastrow1
              If Cells(j, 3) = dés Then
              codeproduit = Cells(j, 1)
              End If
            Next j
              For i = 12 To lastrow1
                If Cells(i, 1) = codeproduit And Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i, 2) Then
                For k = 0 To ListBox4.ListCount - 1
                    If Cells(i, 3) = ListBox4.List(k, 0) Then
                    add = ListBox4.List(k, 5)
                    quantité = quantité + add
                    End If
                Next k
        End If
         Next i
            ListBox2.List(t, 1) = quantité
       Next t
```

I believe that the "quantité" and "Listbox4.list(k,5)" do not match, but why?

Comment: Your code is implicitly working off the active sheet, which makes it more frail than it needs to be. Consider qualifying the `Cells` calls with an explicit `Worksheet` object, preferably using a `With` block.

Comment: Either `Cells(j, 3)` or `Cells(i, 3)` contains an error value, which cannot be compared to a `String`. You need to fix the data, and then fix the code so that errors in data don't throw a *type mismatch*. Use the `IsError` function to determine whether a cell contains an error value.